# How to tell T-SQL query not to escape the given string/query result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

This is a sample query

```
select *
from tablename
where tableid in (<sub query>);
```

The `<sub query>` here returns null or a string of pattern `'id1','id2','id3'`

My `<sub query>` is something like:

```
select xml_data.value('(/Node/SubNode)[1]', 'varchar(max)'))
from tablename
where tableid = '9944169f-95a6-4570-89d7-b57a3fe1b693'
```

**The problem** :
My sub query returns proper data (`'id1','id2','id3'`) but the parent query considers the complete result as one single string and hence returns 0 rows always.

How can I tell SQL Server not to escape single quotes present in the result of my sub-query?

Comment: It's *not* escaping the result. If the result of the inner query is a *single* string containing the *text* "'id1','id2','id3'", SQL Server is *not* going to look inside that string, see the commas, and decide to *convert* that result into 3 separate values.

Comment: i know, i've been using sql in the current fashion since beginning. But now i want the other way round... :(

Comment: Thanks Damien, ur approach of Split function solved my problem. I wonder why u deleted that comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear if your subquery is applying to the same table as the first query, but this should show you the general direction

```
declare @x xml = '<Node><SubNode>t1</SubNode><SubNode>t2</SubNode></Node>'

declare @t  table (v varchar(20))
insert @t values ('t1'),('t3')

select table1.*
from
    @t table1
        inner join 
    @x.nodes('/Node/SubNode') t(x)
        on table1.v = t.x.value('.','varchar(100)')
```